# laravel How to select articles with current language?

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new to laravel and i downloaded a starter site here, 
https://github.com/mrakodol/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site

The site save language in table includes id, lang_code (e.g en), and the article database has a column "language_id" which seems to be used for filtering by language. But in the homecontroller, i see this line:

```
$articles = Article::with('author')->orderBy('position', 'DESC')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(4)->get();
```

This line select all the articles and print it out without language filter. How can i select article only in current language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [where](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) for filtering columns. It of course depends on what kind of id's given for languages. You need to check db.

```
$articles = Article::with('author')->where('language_id',1)->orderBy('position', 'DESC')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(4)->get();
```

Comment: but how do i get the current language id?

Comment: well it depends on how users choose their language on the web site.

Comment: i can get the lang_code, but how to get the id with corresponding lang_id?